# Debug both javascript and c# in ASP.NET Core MVC using VS Code

Tags: javascript, c#, debugging, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to set breakpoints and debug javascript and c# at the same time in VS Code (on macOS)?

I have installed the [chrome debugger extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code) and then created a new MVC app using `dotnet new mvc`.

But when I launch the app breakpoint are only hit in the C# files, they stay grayed out in the js files (site.js) because no symbols have been loaded.

These are my launch settings (the only thing I have modified is `osx` `command` because chrome is not my default browser on macOS):

```
"version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/Foo.PhotoSite.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
            }
```

Comment: Great question that deserves and answer.  I don't see a way to do it and would love to know the official answer

Comment: Why do you need to debug in the same place? Separate the things; Use Chrome developer tools for your html,js, css, etc. files. After all, they are two different kind of animals.

Comment: @Gi1ber7 Because IMHO that is the most obvious thing one would want to do when developing both frontend and backend at the same time. It is called frictionless development. Switching tools always comes at a cost espeically since VS Code is extremely good at debugging both JavaScript and .NET code - just not at the same (or so I thought - fortunately I was proven wrong by Uwe).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want to do is debug 2 different processes. With your configuration you debug the server. If you want to debug the browser as well you have 2 options.

**First** option, just start a second debug session. VS Code will automatically start multi-target debugging. You will want to start an "attach to chrome" session (see below for configuration sample) or "Launch chrome" session. After that you debug the chrome instance you picked or started and the server.

**Second** option, possibly more convenient if you do it a lot is to create a compound. Results in the same thing but you can start it with one click.
In this case you could remove your launch browser configurations that start your browser unless you attach to that instance.

*To get it running you can try your browser configuration separately. Make chrome debugging work correctly (ignore the server) and then combine it in the compound.*

Example with 2 chrome configurations for launching or attaching:

Configuration should look like this:
Please keep in mind that I took it from my Windows machine in case there are special notations for macOS or different debugging ports.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            // ...your configuration for .NET Core here... 
            // called .NET Core Launch (web)
        }
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "LaunchChrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            // This one in case you manually start 2 debug sessions.
            // Like first .net core 
            // then attach to the browser that was started.
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "AttachChrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Debug MVC and Chrome",
            "configurations": [".NET Core Launch (web)", "LaunchChrome"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Essentially you use 2 different debugging extensions. The .NET debugger extension and the chrome debugger extension. Hence the 2 different configuration parts.

**Reference:**
Microsoft calls it "multitarget-debugging" in VS Code. See the docs here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_multitarget-debugging

Comment: Seems awesome, I did this exactly but my JavaScript breakpoints are still greyed out as an unverified breakpoint.

Comment: @DanielJackson I think it has something to do with Source Maps. I've managed all sorts of ways to get the debugger started, but I still can't debug in VS Code

Answer (score 2):

`serverReadyAction` recommended over `launchBrowser`

if you create a new reactredux net core application with `dotnet new reactredux -n testreactredux` browser launches but still not debuggable until change `action` to `debugWithChrome` as following

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",    
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/testreactredux.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "debugWithChrome", // <---- CHANGE HERE ( default is 'openExternally' )
                "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

this way if I place breakpoint on c# code debugger will hit

[image]

and either on javascript ( I used typescript tsx )

[image]

I noted that breakpoint on js code still gray at start but then it stop there correctly.

Comment: I have the same setup with a .NET Core application and an Angular front-end. However, when I stop the debugging, it seems to stop the .NET Core application but the angular application is still running. Trying to stop it again results in "No debug adapter, can not send 'terminate'". Any idea what the issue might be? The debugging for front- and back-end works flawlessly.

Comment: Don't know if this can be of help, but as seen from sshoot I used chrome and in vscode I installed "Debugger for Chrome" extension.

Comment: The add-on is installed and the debugging is working. It is more of an issue that the debugging session doesn't stop properly.

Comment: Ok, now I understood, I never seen that message but searching for that I found that seems a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/89658#issuecomment-595169453) when the session stop; I suggest you to check if you use vscode insider after [this change](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/33e56c6b51b29eb9bc2ec1a024c932b6cb416379) past to 5mar watching at [releases](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tags) from 1.43.0 it should ok I think.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine changing action "openExternally" to "debugWithChrome".

Less code and more functional than composing with "compounds". Thanks to Lorenzo Delana!

```
    "version": "0.2.0",    
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/testreactredux.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "debugWithChrome", // <---- CHANGE HERE ( default is 'openExternally' )
                "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```